# PHP stdObject - dynamically assigned function returns a reference

Tags: php

I am using the stdObject methodology in my program, and essentially wondering if it is possible to return a reference :

```
//standard way using classes

$txt='hello';

class test {
  function & gettxt(){
    global $txt;
    return $txt;
  }
  function disp(){
    global $txt;
    echo $txt;
  }
}
$o=new test();
$txt_ref=& $o->gettxt();
$txt_ref='world';
$o->disp();//displays world
```

[php.net : anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#Hcom113896)

sugguests this syntax :

```
//codefragment1:

//from php.net
class stdObject {
  public function __call($method,$arguments){
    if(isset($this->{$method})&&(is_callable($this->{$method}))
      return call_user_func_array($this->{$method},$arguments);
    else
      throw new Exception("Fatal error: Call to undefined method, $method");
  }
}

$txt='hello';

$o=new stdObject();
$o->getvalue=function & () use (&$txt) { return $txt;};
$o->disp=function() use (&$txt) { echo $txt;};

$txt_ref=& $o->getvalue();//error only variables should be assigned by reference
$txt_ref='world';
$o->disp();//hoping for 'world'
```

Comment: [link]http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php

Comment: It's not completely clear what do you want to achieve.  Do you need a reference for function variable?

Comment: in codefragment1 i would like getvalue to return a reference to $txt

Comment: partial solution as per [php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php#Hcom39841](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php#Hcom39841)

Comment: so im thinking that the problem essentially lies in that the __call function is not declared to return a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class stdobject {

  function & __call($method,$args){

    if(substr($method,-1)==='_')
      $r=& ($this->{$method})();
    else
      $r=($this->{$method})();
    return $r;

  }

}

$txt='hello';

$o=new stdobject();
$o->getvalue_=function & () use (&$txt) { return $txt;};
$o->disp=function () use (&$txt) { echo $txt; };

$txt_ref=& $o->getvalue_();
$txt_ref='world';
$o->disp();  // world
```

well i settled on this solution

- php7
- it uses a programming convention that functions that return a reference should be declared with their names ending in an underscore
- this example does not provide arguments to the function, but can be incorporated using a variety of methods
- php5 requires functions returning references to be written as

  ```
  $fn=$o->getvalue_;
  $r=& $fn();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing is a bad idea as it breaks the rule of Encapsulation in Object Oriented programming because you are trying to gain a direct reference to an object's internal property, and that is generally prohibited in OO.

The correct way to achieve it is by adding a setter method:

```
class test {
    public setValue($val)
    {
       $this->value = $val;
    }
}
```

However, if you insist on breaking the rules of OO programming you can do it this way by making the object's internal property public:

```
class test {
    public $value;
}

$o=new test();
$o->value = 'world';
```

Comment: ive been trying to simplify the working code useage, i am using the stdObject methodology for a variety of reasons, non polution of global splace, the way i am storing and loading code also, ive essentially solved the working code problem by returning an array index rather than a reference to an array, so am asking the question mostly for academic reasons